# Deriving entropy of ideal gas from Maxwell Boltzmann Distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In class, my professor said from the definition entropy $ -k_b \sum p_i \log  p_i$ and the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution of velocity $P(v)= \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_b T}\right)^{3/2} \exp  \left(\frac{m|v|^2}{2k_bT}\right) $, you can derive entropy of an ideal gas. I think that if you use the quantization of energy and find the partition function you can avoid most of that mess, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this purely mathematically without invoking quantum. I think there is something you can do with the sum to make it integral, but I'm pretty lost as to how.

Comment: can you please be more specific? what is the "mess" you are referring to and trying to avoid? is it the presentation of the entropy as a sum instead of an integral?

Comment: Plug the distribution into the equation for entropy and intergrate over velocities: $\sum_i\rightarrow \int dv$.